# Find sets which are subsets of the given search set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sets

The problem is the following:
You are given a collection( set, list, whatever ) C of sets, and you are given a search set S.
We want to find among all sets in C the ones which are subsets of S.
Hence, the statement would be:
What is the best way to return all sets from C which are a subset of search set S?

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120493/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75915/755, as well as https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7701/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109399/755 (take complements of all sets)

Comment: I'm not looking for element of C to be superset of S, but for element of C to be subset of S, so the other way around.

Comment: If you "take complements of all sets", that swaps superset vs subset, showing a close connection between those two problems and allowing you to apply techniques for one to solve the other.